# CSS animating text color on hover doesn't work

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-animations

I have three cards on my page, made with their individual divs, which I want to animate when the user hovers over them. I want to change the background of the divs a little, make the text white from black, and increase the font size a little. The code for it is

```css
@keyframes card-highlight {
  from {
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    font-size: 2rem;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  }
  to {
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font-size: 2.2rem;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  }
}

.with-padding {
  margin: 90px 50px;
  padding: 150px 0px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  border: 3px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  color: black;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.with-padding:hover {
  animation-name: card-highlight;
  animation-duration: 0.3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

```html
<div class='row second-page'>
  <div class='col-xl-3 col-md-6 col-sm-12 with-padding'>
    <a href=''>
      <h1>- About -</h1>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class='col-xl-3 col-md-6 col-sm-12 with-padding'>
    <a href=''>
      <h1>- Projects -</h1>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class='col-xl-3 col-md-6 col-sm-12 with-padding'>
    <a href=''>
      <h1>- Résumé -</h1>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, when I hover over the element, only the background color changes, but not the text color and the font size.
I am using bootstrap, but I don't think it should have any effect on the animation, right? Plus, I am animating the font color elsewhere on the page, and that works. The CSS for that is

```
@keyframes colorfadein-transparent {
    from{color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);}
    to{color: rgb(80, 80, 80);}
}

.different-font {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    font-size: 180px;
    font-family: 'Fredericka the Great', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;

    animation-name: colorfadein-transparent;
    animation-delay: 0.5s;
    animation-duration: 0.6s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```css
.with-padding {
    margin: 90px 50px;
    padding: 150px 0px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    border: 3px solid black;

    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: center;

    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    color: black;
    font-size: 2rem;
    transition: 1s;
}

.with-padding:hover{
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<div class='row second-page'>
    <div class='col-xl-3 col-md-6 col-sm-12 with-padding'>
        <a href=''>
        <h1>- About -</h1>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class='col-xl-3 col-md-6 col-sm-12 with-padding'>
        <a href=''>
        <h1>- Projects -</h1>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class='col-xl-3 col-md-6 col-sm-12 with-padding'>
        <a href=''>
        <h1>- Résumé -</h1>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope its useful for you :)

Answer (score 1):

I thinks, it's cause by CSS links `a`, change `.with-padding:hover` by `.with-padding:hover a`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `@keyframes` for this you can get the desired result with a simple `transition: all .3s;` all i did is add that to your `.with-padding` class and added the code you had in your animation to `.with-padding:hover`

```css
.with-padding {
  margin: 90px 50px;
  padding: 150px 0px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  border: 3px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  color: black;
  font-size: 2rem;
  transition: all .3s;
}

.with-padding a {
  color: black;
  font-size: 2rem;
  transition: all .3s;
}

.with-padding:hover {

  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}

.with-padding:hover a {
  color: white;
  font-size: 2.2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class='row second-page'>
  <div class='col-xl-3 col-md-6 col-sm-12 with-padding'>
    <a href=''>
      <h1>- About -</h1>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class='col-xl-3 col-md-6 col-sm-12 with-padding'>
    <a href=''>
      <h1>- Projects -</h1>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class='col-xl-3 col-md-6 col-sm-12 with-padding'>
    <a href=''>
      <h1>- Résumé -</h1>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```